# Scheduled Personal Software Audit / Inventory

Tags: windows-7, backup

Im trying to be very pro-active with getting a good backup now as my entire digital life as it were is on my laptop inc music etc.

I currently take a USB drive backup and an online backup, however i would like to be able to make a list of all software installed along with licence keys if possible (although this isn't essential as i keep a copy in my lastpass database)

The idea would be that i could schedule a task to run the audit once a week which stores the report and get backed up, then in a disaster scenario i can get windows running again, begin downloading my backup and print off my software list so i can get everything installed again, i always seem to forget something when i reload so something like this would be quite handy to get myself back to 100% with the minimum of fuss.

I am aware of belarc advisor which arguably creates pretty much the report i need, but I could not find any references to being able to schedule a task and specify the output location of the report, if this is possible maybe this will be the best solution, id be appreciative of any suggestions anyone may have.

Current setup FWIW is Windows 7 64Bit

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the advisor installed here, but if I remember correctly the audit can start by running a single executable that has been installed. If I indeed remembered correctly all you need to do is schedule a task, which can be googled for pretty easily, the best result might be the [microsoft "tutorial"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Schedule-a-task)